# Замена тега script из js

Tags: javascript

На странице js код заключен в тег "script"

Возможно ли из js, заменить данный тег. Не выполняя поиск по документу и не присваивая никаких индетификаторов.

То есть заменить тег так, словно обращаемся из кода(в данном теге) к данному тегу как к родителю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) указывает на тег `<script>`, внутри которого был выполнен.

```html
<div>1</div>

<script>
  console.log(document.currentScript.outerHTML);
  document.currentScript.outerHTML = '<div>2</div>';  
</script>

<div>3</div>
```

Если порядок скриптов на странице заранее известен, можно использовать селектор тега:

```html
<script>1;</script>
<script>2;</script>
<script>
  let script = document.querySelectorAll('script');
  
  console.log( script[0] );
  console.log( script[1] );
  console.log( script[2] );

  script[3].parentNode.removeChild( script[3] ); // Удален.
</script>
```

*Примечание*: От удаления тега скрипт не перестанет работать.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а почему ?

Comment: @Staxcelrom Потому что браузер читает и "применяет" скрипт сразу. Как только он выполнен и сохранен в память, уже нельзя отменить (не зная, что конкретно он выполнил, чтобы вручную повыполнять все обратные действия).

Comment: понял, спасибо! То есть получается, если нужно чтобы браузер запускал именно измененный скрипт - его нужно изменять во время получения ?

Comment: @Staxcelrom Да)